# Hide both input cell and output cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks

You can double-click the right gutter of a input cell to hide a corresponding output cell or double-click the gutter of the output cell to hide the input cell.

I would like to hide both the input and the output cell. Is this possible to do within the GUI?

Comment: Yes: select both cells, then **Menu** > **Cell** > **Cell Properties** and un-check **Open**.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Alright, I shall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can hide both Input and Output cells, as well as any other type, by setting the Cell expression option `CellOpen` to `False`.  This is most frequently done by:

1. Selecting the entire cell or cells using the cell brackets
2. Following the Menu path: **Cell** > **Cell Properties** and un-checking **Open**.

It can also be done using the **[Option Inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OptionInspector.html)** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on Windows), or programmatically with e.g. [`SelectionMove`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SelectionMove.html) and [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetOptions.html).

In addition to closing the cells you can also collapse the cell group as described in your question or by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> to produce a very compact structure with only a minimal bracket remaining for selection.

Comment: This is useful. But it will be much more useful if the closed cell leave some information of cell (at least the first line of the cell), so users can know what is this closed cell contain. But now it is just narrow blank line, hard to notice.

Comment: I have to write a comment to indicate that "hey! there is a cell hiding here! check it out!" :)